# How to get only the 1st element of an large array in JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have been looking at the Streaming implementation of the Gson Library. But I cannot determine if it would be a good practice to do like the following to get the 1st element of an array. The URL returns an `InputStream` which contains a Json array.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
reader.beginArray();
Message message = new gson().fromJson(reader, Message.class);
reader.endArray(); // this line
reader.close();
```

My question lies on the line that has the comment beside. Should I do that if I want only to get the first element?

Note that here I want to know about the efficiency of the code. The code is directly copied from the gson streaming example [with some modification to describe the situation correctly].

The actual array is very large. That's why I cannot just wait to get the whole array and then get the element. So I want to break the process as soon as I get the first element and then close the stream.

Also please recommend me of any better approach if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that here I want to know about the efficiency of the code

Well, then look at the code :) [Source for JsonReader](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.java?r=832)

It does pretty much what you would expect. It's using the provided `InputStreamReader` and only reading what it needs to fulfill an operation (in your case, getting the first object from the JSON array).

However ... when you call `endArray()` ... it's going to read from the stream until it finds the closing `]` of that array. You don't actually care about that, and certainly don't want to spend the time reading all that data from the wire. Just call `close()`.

Since you're closing the `JsonReader` (and thus the underlying stream)  ... that's about as good as you're going to get. You only read the data you wanted from the underlying stream then closed it.

**Edit from comments:** You can make your cases nice and tidy by doing:

```
public Message getFirstMessageFromArray(JsonReader reader) {
    reader.beginArray();
    return getMessageFromJson(reader);
}

public Message getMessageFromJson(JsonReader reader) {
    return new gson().fromJson(reader, Message.class);
}
```

And when you wanted to use it:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
Message message = getFirstMessageFromArray(reader);
reader.close();
```

or

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
Message message = getMessageFromJson(reader);
reader.close();
```

Comment: Thanks...Really helped me a lot. So that means If I just call close, it would do my work...

Comment: Yep. You already have your `MessageObject`, just call `reader.close()` after that and go on your merry way.

Comment: Okay, now in the next sequence I receive only one `MessageObject` and not an Array. How should I deal with it? Simple `gson.fromJson(...)` would do nice?

Comment: Yeah. If you know the input stream just contains a single JSON object do the same thing except without calling `beginArray()`.

Comment: Thanks...I know it only contains one `Object`...Thanks again... :D

Comment: You could even abstract that into a couple methods where the first one called `beginArray` then passed the `JsonReader` to the second one which actually did the JSON call. Then only call the second one when you don't have an array.

Comment: Exactly. I was just thinking of the same thing. It will just simplify the code a lot...Thanks...